# Ошибка. Два класса содержат элементы типа данных друг друга. Не работает include

Tags: c++, visual-studio

student.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Course.h"
using namespace std;

class Student
{
     //overload input output streams
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const Student &);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &, Student &);

private:
    string name;
    long id;
    char gender;
    int age;

    Course** coursesOfStudent; // list of pointer to courser for student
    //Department *studentDepartment; // pointer to department

public:
    static int studentsCounter; // count num of elements
    Student();
    // set get block
    void set(string, long, char, int);
    string getName() { return name; }
    long getId() { return id; }
    char getGender() { return gender; }
    int getAge() { return age;  }

    // overload block 
    Student &operator=(const Student &); // instead copy constructor
    bool operator==(const Student &) const; // check if the same student by id number
    bool operator>(const Student &) const; // check if average of one student greater than avarage another
    //void operator+=(const Course &); // add new course to course list of the student
    //void operator-=(const Course &); // remove course from course list of the student
    //Course* operator[](int index); // return pointer to course by index

    int countAverage() {} // help function to count average for the student

    ~Student();
};
```

Course.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

class Course
{
    // overload input output streams
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const Course &);
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &, Course &);

private:
    Student** studentsOfCourse; // list of pointers studetns of course
    string name;
    long id;
    int* points; // list of point students by the course 
    //Department* departmentOfCourse; // pointer to department

public:
    static int coursesCounter; // count num of elements
    Course();
    // set get block
    void setId(long);


    string getName() { return name; }
    long getId() { return id; }

    // overload block 
    Course &operator=(const Course &); // instead copy constructor
    bool operator==(const Course &) const; // check if the same student by id number
    bool operator>(const Course &) const; // check if average of one student greater than avarage another
    void operator+=(const Course &); // add new course to course list of the student
    void operator-=(const Course &); // remove course from course list of the student
    //Student* operator[](int index); // return pointer to course by index

    ~Course();
};
```

Один класс содержит элемент второго и наоборот. Без `#pragma`, `once` пишет *include itself*, а с `#pragma` `once` не видит одного из элементов (Student или Course).

Как сделать, чтобы все работало?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Используйте fast forward declaration. Например, первый файл оставяем как есть, а начало второго переписываем так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Student;

class Course
{
```

и обязательно `#pragma once` в каждый .h файл или с помощью ifndef - define.